# Why am I getting two Content View?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

When try to create a new Xamarin.Forms page it's show option to create two Content View.
[Page Creation layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Tft.png)

Comment: You'll need to provide some code if you want an answer.

Comment: I think you are talking about contentview.Xaml and other is contentview.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in older Visual-Studio and I just confirm that it has been fixed in latest version `16.6.2`.

You can update your Visual-Studio to solve this problem:).

Answer (score 0):

It is just a bug, you can use whichever.